# Implement Lambda@Edge authentication for CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I am looking to add the Lambda@Edge to one of our services. The goal is to regex the url for certain values and compare those against a header value to ensure authorization. If the value is present then it is compared and if rejected should return a 403 immediately to the user. If the value compared matches or the url doesn't contain a particular value, then the request continues on as an authorized request.

Initially I was thinking that this would occur with a "viewer request" event. Some of the posts and comments on SO suggest that the "origin request" is more ideal for this check. But right now I've been trying to play around with the examples in the documentation on one of our CF end points but I'm not seeing expected results. The code is the following:

```
'use strict';
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    request.headers["edge-test"] = [{
        key:   'edge-test', 
        value: Date.now().toString()
    }];

    console.log(require('util').inspect(event, { depth: null }));

    callback(null, request);
};
```

I would expect that there should be a logged value inside cloudwatch and a new header value in the request, yet I'm not seeing any logs nor am I seeing the header value when the request comes in.

Can someone shed some light on why things don't seem to be executing as to what I would think should be the response? Is my understanding of what the expected output wrong? Is there configuration that I may be missing (My distribution ID on the trigger is set to the instance we want, and the behavior was set to '*')? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: I think I've addressed your main issue, below, but worth noting is that when you update your Lambda function and push out a new trigger, your site is going to be unprotected for a few seconds.  Trigger updates do not appear to be atomic, at least not if you allow Lambda to control them... it's a delete + add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a few notes;

CloudFront is (among other things) a web cache.

A web cache's purpose is to serve content directly to the browser instead of sending the request to the origin server.

However, one of the most critical things a cache must do correctly is **not** return the wrong content.  One of the ways a cache can return the wrong content is by not realizing that certain request headers may cause the orogin server to vary the response it returns for a given URI.

CloudFront has no perfect way of knowing this, so its solution -- by default -- is to remove almost all of the headers from the request before forwarding it to the origin.  Then it caches the received response against *exactly* the request that it sent to the origin, and will only use that cached response for future *identical* requests.

Injecting a new header in a Viewer Request trigger will cause that header to be discarded after it passes through the matching Cache Behavior, unless the cache behavior specifically is configured to whitelist that header for forwarding to the origin.  This is the same behavior you would see if the header had been injected by the browser, itself.

So, your solution to get this header to pass through to the origin is to whitelist it in the cache behavior settings.

If you tried this same code as an Origin Request trigger, without the header whitelisted, CloudFront would actually throw a `502 Bad Gateway` error, because you're trying to inject a header that CloudFront already knows you haven't whitelisted in the matching Cache Behavior. (In Viewer Request, the Cache Behavior match hasn't yet occurred, so CloudFront can't tell if you're doing something with the headers that will not ultimately work. In Origin Request, it knows.)  The flow is Viewer Request > Cache Behavior > Cache Check > (if cache miss) Origin Request > send to Origin Server.  Whitelisting the header would resolve this, as well.

Any header you want the origin to see, whether it comes from the browser, or a request trigger, must be whitelisted.

Note that [some headers are inaccessible or immutable](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-header-restrictions.html), particularly those that could be used to co-opt CloudFront for fraudulent purposes (such as request forgery and spoofing) and those that simply make no sense to modify.

Comment: Ok, makes sense, but what about the log? If the trigger is actually triggered, shouldn't I see the CloudWatch log entry?

Comment: [If the permissions are correct](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html#lambda-edge-permissions), it should.  The docs say it writes logs to us-east-1, but that may not always be true, based on some other changes I observed right before the service launched.  It might log in the region nearest the edge where the trigger fires.  I'll need to check that.

Comment: Right now the role attached is one that we use on all of our standard lambdas. The policy for logging to cloudwatch is:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: You were correct! I managed to find the logs you were referring to. They were located inside the region where the endpoint was being called. Because of the prefix added, it was at the end of our list. (we have 600+ logged services)

Comment: Excellent. It appears I misread the documentation, in any event.  [*"Lambda creates CloudWatch Logs log streams in the CloudWatch Logs regions closest to the locations where the function is executed. The format of the name for each log stream is `/aws/lambda/us-east-1.function-name` where `function-name` is the name that you gave to the function when you created it."*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-cloudwatch-metrics-logging.html)